# Async test in Jest failing due to unresolved promise

Tags: javascript, es6-promise, jestjs

I am learning Jest and running into an issue trying to mock an async function that returns a `fetch` promise.

In their docs, there is this: 
"If a promise doesn't resolve at all, this error might be thrown:
- Error: Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by `jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.`
Most commonly this is being caused by conflicting Promise implementations. Consider replacing the global promise implementation with your own, for example `global.Promise = require.requireActual('promise');` and/or consolidate the used Promise libraries to a single one."

This likely is the issue, but it's unclear to me how to fix my issue or determine where the `Promise` is breaking.

Maybe my understanding of mocks in Jest is wrong? I tried using their example and it worked perfectly of course. (https://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/tutorial-async.html#content)

This is what I get in the console:

```
● endpoint can receive form data › can parse and fulfill a promise

    Timeout - Async callback was not invoked within timeout specified by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL.
```

Here are my modules and test:

```
// myModule/index.js
import { OK } from 'http-status-codes';
import request from './request';
import parseForm from '../../../../modules/parseMultiPart';

export default (req, res, next) => parseForm(req)
    .then(body => request(body, req)
    .then(result => result.text())
    .then(result => res.status(OK).send(result)))
.catch(next);


// myModule/request.js
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

export default (body, req) => fetch('http://url', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify(body.fields),
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        'X-Request-Id': req.id
    }
});


// myModule/__tests__/myModule.test.js
import MockReq from 'mock-req';
import MockRes from 'mock-res';
import myModule from '../';

jest.mock('../request');

describe('endpoint can receive form data', () => {
    const response = new MockRes();
    const request = new MockReq({
        method: 'POST',
        url: '/webhook',
        headers: {
            'Content-Disposition': 'form-data; name="file"; filename="plain.txt"',
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data; custom=stuff; boundary=----TLV0SrKD4z1TRxRhAPUvZ',
            'Content-Length': 213
        }
    });

    it('can parse and fulfill a promise', () => myModule(request, response)
        .then(text => expect(text).toEqual('API Event Received'))
    );
});


// myModule/__mocks__/request.js
export default function request() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
        process.nextTick(
            () => resolve('API Event Received')
        );
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was mocking the wrong thing. Needed to be mocking the functions, not the data in this case:

```
jest.mock('../parseMultiPart');
jest.mock('../request');
```

My request wasn't correct and the Promise was never returning.